# How to limit tx_news teaser and bodytext length in Backend TCA?

Tags: typo3, tsconfig, tx-news

For limiting the maximum length of a news title, i can use this tsConfig setting:

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.title.config.max = 70
```

Is it possible to set such a limitation also for teaser and bodytext of news records? Since these are not simple input fields but textareas or RTE fields, it doesn´t seem to be that easy to limit their length. Is it possible nevertheless?

Answer (score 1):

`max` does not apply to RTE fields. You can try to limit the length in an editor plugin, e.g. [CK Editor Plugin](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Character-Count-Plugin) (for TYPO3 8).
Keep in mind that there is not server side length validation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `typo3conf/ext/news/Resources/Private/Partials/List/Item.html` here you can find the setting `settings.cropMaxCharacters`, so if you set `plugin.tx_news.settings.cropMaxCharacters = 150` your text displayed with max 150 Chars.

Answer (score 0):

Your Typoscript is correct for `title` and syntax is also correct: `TCEFORM.[table name].[field].config.[key] = value`

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.title.config.max = 70
```

If you want set limit for `bodytext` and `teaser` then try to below typoscript

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.bodytext.config.Type = TEXT
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.bodytext.config.Rows = 2
```

Also Add this typoscript in Root Page TSConfig.

More Details. [Click Here](http://labor.99grad.de/2016/11/26/typo3-tca-default-werte-per-tsconfig-setzen/)